# On close tab ask for unsaved changes and then reload the page - How?

Tags: javascript

I've come across a nasty website that managed to refresh the page every time I tried to close the tab. Basically you couldn't close that page. I got around it by disabling javascript on that page.

**How do they do it?**

I've tried `location.replace` inside `onbeforeunload` and it doesn't work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  window.location.replace(window.location.href);
};
```

Here is the source of the page in question, where I don't get how they do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function c(b)
        {
            document.write(b);
        }

        function wrapped3(d)
        {
            return d.replace(/(.)(.)/g, '%$1$2');
        }

        function wrapped(b)
        {
            var tmp = window['decodeURI' + 'Component'];
            return tmp(wrapped3(b))
        }

        function show_page(a)
        {
            c(wrapped(a)
                .split('{{addr}}').join('//ip')
                .split('{{country}}').join('Great Britain')
                .split('{{region}}').join('London, City of')
                .split('{{city}}').join('London')
                .split('{{ltude}}').join('//latitude')
                .split('{{referrer}}').join('//url here')
            );
        }
        show_page('//long string here');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.onbeforeunload is the correct solution, here is an example:

```
     var popit = true;
     window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
          if(popit == true) {
               popit = false;
               return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; 
          }
     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SQAmG/3/